# ExtentReport tests end time is the same as start time

Tags: selenium, extentreports

i'm using extentreports to generate an html report file and the start and finish times of each test are the same and i don't know what i'm doing wrong.

```
    import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentTest;

public static ExtentReports extent;
public static ExtentTest extentTest;


 extent = new ExtentReports("" + projectDirectoryPath + "junit_debug_report\\"+ browser+ "\\" + date + "extentReportFile.html", false);

 @BeforeClass
    public static  void a_logIn() throws Exception {

        extentTest = extent.startTest("Interactions tests",
                "Interactions tests").assignCategory("CP","account", "Interactions");
        System.out.println("Interactions tests");
        String testStr = "login";
        try {
            ....
            extentTest.log(LogStatus.PASS, testStr);
        }catch (Exception e){
            reportError(e.toString());
        }
    }

@AfterClass
    public static  void b_logout() throws Exception {
        String testStr ="logout";
        try{
            ....
            extentTest.log(LogStatus.PASS, testStr);
            extent.endTest(extentTest);
        }catch (Exception e){
            reportError( e.toString() );
        }
    }
```

do i need to update the end time manually with this?

```
extentTest.setEndedTime(new Date());
```

i'm trying to avoid it because i need to add it to each test, and i have a lot.
here is a pic from report

[image]

Comment: Can you try with version extent report 3.1.5

Comment: i cant find this version, i'm using this:https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.relevantcodes/extentreports/2.40.2

Comment: Its now replaced by https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports/3.1.5

Comment: Version 2 reached end is life more than 1 year ago.. please upgrade to version 3. Version 4 is right around the corner, and usage would be almost identical to 3.

Comment: i just added the manual time stamp update, it was easy apparently. but i will update my version any way, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're instantiate Your extent tests in `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass`, and test instance for extent is called only once, that is why You have same times. Try instantiate Your extent tests same as driver before each test, not class.

use `@BeforeTest, @AfterTest` / @`BeforeMethod, @AfterMethod` depending on which test framework are You using.

Hope this helps,